# Fetch Column from second table using date from first table if the date is in between dates from second table

Tags: mysql

I have my first table here:

[image]

Then i have my second table here:

[image]

My problem is that, I needed to **get the right corresponding ShiftAssignmentShiftID From second table if the selected_date from first table is in between the start date and end date of the second table.**  In short, I needed to get/display what shift of the employee is, per day. **But I am getting all the ShiftAssignmentShiftID ALL as NULL values.**

Here's my query:

```
SELECT FirstColumns.selected_date,FirstColumns.WeekDay,FirstColumns.EmployeeName,FirstColumns.EmployeeID, tblshiftassignments.ShiftAssignmentShiftID  FROM (select EmployeeID,selected_date,CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(selected_date) = 0 THEN 'MON' WHEN WEEKDAY(selected_date) = 1 THEN 'TUES' WHEN WEEKDAY(selected_date) = 2 THEN 'WED' WHEN WEEKDAY(selected_date) = 3 THEN 'THU' WHEN WEEKDAY(selected_date) = 4 THEN 'FRI' WHEN WEEKDAY(selected_date) = 5 THEN 'SAT' WHEN WEEKDAY(selected_date) = 6 THEN 'SUN' END AS 'WeekDay', tblemployee.EmployeeIDDisplay, CONCAT(tblemployee.EmployeeLastName,',',tblemployee.EmployeeFirstName) AS 'EmployeeName' from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v,
 tblemployee 
where selected_date between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-30'
order by tblemployee.EmployeeLastName, selected_date) AS FirstColumns LEFT JOIN tblshiftassignments ON tblshiftassignments.ShiftAssignmentEmployeeID = FirstColumns.EmployeeID AND tblshiftassignments.ShiftAssignmentStartDate <= FirstColumns.selected_date AND tblshiftassignments.ShiftAssignmentEndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY > FirstColumns.selected_date

ORDER BY FirstColumns.EmployeeName,selected_date
```

Here's my desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! All my queries are correct. The dates that i was testing was 2021 but the data in the table is 2020, i missed this one out. That's why it's returning NULL.